# Expectation and Indicator Functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory

It is proven [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/nprivault/MAS328/MAS328-1.pdf) on page 24 that for a discrete random variable $X$ and an event $A$ with $P(A)>0$ then $E[X|A]=\frac{E[X1_{A}]}{P(A)}$.

Following the lecture notes at page 29 that it is also true for continuous random variables. Is there any way to prove this?

Comment: Ain't it the *definition*?

Answer (score 1):

Since $X$ is a random variable, defined in relation to a probability space $(S, \mathcal F, P)$, then for any event $A \in \mathcal F$ we have that there exists a Borel set $B_A \subset \mathbb R$ such that

$$X^{-1}(B_A) = \{s:X(s) \in B_A, s\in S\} = A \Rightarrow B_A = X(A)$$

So "$A$ happens" is equivalent to restricting the range of $X$ to $B_A$, $1_A = 1 \Rightarrow X\in B_A$. So

$$1_A = 1_{\{X\in B_A\}} \Rightarrow E[1_A] = E[1_{\{X\in B_A\}}] \Rightarrow P(A) = P(X\in B_A)$$.

Using these equalities we have (using also the assumption of the notes the OP refers to about an absolutely continuous r.v.)
$$E[X1_A] = E[X1_{\{X\in B_A\}}]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\cdot 1_{\{X\in B_A\}}f_X(x)dx = \int_{B_A}xf_X(x)dx$$
$$=P(X\in B_A)\int_{B_A}x\frac {f_X(x)}{P(X\in B_A)}dx = P(X\in B_A)\cdot  E[X\mid X\in B_A]$$
$$\Rightarrow E[X1_A] = P(A)\cdot E[X\mid A]$$

Comment: Wait, are you saying that every $A$ in $\mathcal F$ belongs to the sigma-algebra $\sigma(X)$? This seems trivially wrong. // @upvoter Why the upvote?

Comment: When I write "$X$ is a random variable, defined in relation to a probability space $(S, \mathcal F, P)$", I mean "$\mathcal F$ is such that $X$ is a random variable with respect to $\mathcal F$". If there is a better way to express this, I would be happy to re-phrase.

Comment: And this means that $\sigma(X)\subseteq\mathcal F$, not the other way round. Hence the reasoning in your post falls apart at line 2.